# Trying to install micropython-termios 0.0.0

Tags: python, cmd, pip, installation

Hi I'm trying to install micropython-termios 0.0.0 but when I use pip it spits out the following (I used Admin CMD in WINDOWS 10)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install micropython-termios
Collecting micropython-termios
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fd/0e/3de9bc2c848adadcd3af4b7fd67d4c483acd87a76974a00f107a589cfcc0/micropython-termios-0.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\tokenize.py", line 452, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Michael\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-56w335sf\\micropython-termios\\setup.py'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-56w335sf\micropython-termios\
```

How do I (1.) get rid of this message. (2.) Install micropython-termios

Answer (score 1):

From https://pypi.org/project/micropython-termios/#description:

«This is a **dummy** implementation of a module for MicroPython standard library.» (Emphasized by me — phd).

The module is simply not for installation.